# expression must have a constant value in c++

Tags: c++

So, I am creating an object that have an array as it's instance. The size of this array will determined by the client program. Later in my program, I have to create a temp array that have the same capacity as the instance variable. So, I put:

```
int temp[capacity];
```

However, when I try to compile it, it failed. It said that I have to have a fix value instead of putting capacity. Any idea how can I fix this problem? thx

Comment: You should use: `std::vector<int> temp(capacity);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only construct such an array if `capacity` is known at compile time. For dynamically sized arrays, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> temp(capacity); // makes a vector with capacity elements
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `capacity` (other than that `temp.size()` is increased) but are there any other reason?

Comment: @David So that the vector holds ``capacity`` elements, as OP intended to do with the array. The difference here is that the elements will be zero initialized, whereas they wouldn't be with an array.

Comment: *So that the vector holds capacity elements*: but if I add more elements the vector's size will be increased accordingly...

Comment: @David yes, of course. But this allow OP to use it like a fixed size array. Unfortunately there is no dynamically *and* fixed size container in the standard library, but it is easy enough to implement one.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing this:

```
int temp[capacity]
```

Just write:

```
int* temp = (int*)malloc(capacity);
```

Comment: To future readers: Do no use this.  This is undefined behavior and also makes you responsible for cleaning up the memory when you are done.  If you absolutely can't use a `std::vector`, then use `new[]` and `delete[]` instead.